# Hide program icon from taskbar/alt-tab/etc (Not tray) and keep it unminimized?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I want to remove an icon from my taskbar without closing the window itself. To be clear, I'm talking about the taskbar:

[image]

Not the system tray:

[image]

My current solution is using RBTray which minimizes a program to the system tray and removes its icon from the taskbar. The issue with this is that the program is minimized and cannot be opened again until I click the tray icon, which puts it back in the taskbar. I'm fine with it being sent to the tray, but I don't want the window to go away.

Comment: While I don't think this is possible, maybe this method to make the icon nearly invisible, will help you: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/181802-taskbar-pin-invisible-icon-program.html

Comment: All of those answers minimize the program

Comment: This question has _not_ been asked before (note the _unminimized_) and _still_ has _not_ an answer. Those answers do not fully address this question and, though the OP asked here as a new (and more precise) question, has been marked as duplicate. @YisroelTech I know programs that open interactive windows without affecting the taskbar (I use the old Pinnacle PCTV Remote, that creates a tray icon but never appears on taskbar not even when you configure the port used). Anyway, someone should provide a documented answer explaining why this is impossible, if it is so. Please remove the 'duplicate'.

Comment: I've got the same exact need (and am using RBTray right now too)....  can't find a thing :(

Comment: I'm wanting to do this too for the Volume Mixer utility (sndvol.exe).

Answer (score 3):

With Windows 10, you have the ability to create virtual desktops. The programs running on these desktops will not show up at all on other desktops. You could open the window on a separate desktop and switch back when you need it.

How to find virtual desktops:

[image: Task View Button]

Create a new desktop:

[image: Create Desktop Button]

To switch desktops, just hit Task View again and your desktops will be at the bottom of your screen with a preview of that desktop for you to choose between.

Comment: I need all the windows to be open at the same time unfortunately, so this idea would not work for me. It is a very interesting solution though!

Comment: Well, I hope you find your solution.